# Convert dictionary of lists to dictionary of tuples

Tags: python, list, dictionary, tuples, reformatting

Hello everyone I am fairly new to python (so forgive me if this a simple question) and working on multiprocessing with a k-means algorithm but I am having an issue with data formatting. I have a dictionary of lists formatted as so:

```
{0: [122.0, 0.000209], 1: [125.0, 0.000419], 2: [127.0, 0.000233], 3: [120.0, 0.000209], 4: [126.0, 0.000336]}
```

but I need it to be a dictionary of tuples so it looks like:

```
{0: (122.0, 0.000209), 1: (125.0, 0.000419), 2: (127.0, 0.000233), 3: (120.0, 0.000209), 4: (126.0, 0.000336)}.
```

I know you can use the function

```
tuple(list)
```

to convert a list to a tuple but I am sure how to go about iterating through the dictionary and changing each entry to a tuple. Does anyone have any advice on how to go about doing this? Any help is appreciated thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The naive way:

```
for key in dictionary:
    dictionary[key] = tuple(dictionary[key])
```

or the slightly cleaner-looking but otherwise completely identical way:

```
for key, value in dictionary.iteritems():
    dictionary[key] = tuple(value)
```

or the last recast as a dictionary comprehension for even more cleanliness:

```
dictionary = {k: tuple(v) for k,v in dictionary.iteritems()}
```

should all suffice for this particular task.

(In Python 3, use `dictionary.items()` rather than `iteritems()`)

Comment: I don't know if the first method is "naive." It is "in-place" however.

Comment: @JaredGoguen It's the first thing someone might think of to try, hence why I labelled it naive. OP doesn't specify an in-place requirement.

Comment: Thank you sir, exactly what I needed.